# Kafka Consumer - JMX Properties

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I enabled JMX on the kafka brokers on port 8081. When I view the MBean properties in jConsole, I only see the following for `kafka.consumer`-

```
kafka.consumer:type=FetchRequestAndResponseMetrics,name=FetchRequestRateAndTimeMs,clientId=ReplicaFetcherThread-2-413

kafka.consumer:type=FetchRequestAndResponseMetrics,name=FetchResponseSize,clientId=ReplicaFetcherThread-0-413
```

But none of the other ones that are identified in [here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-monitor-kafka/) under Kafka Consumer Metrics are emitted by JMX.

Kafka Version # 0.8.2.1

I am specifically interested in - 
`kafka.consumer:type=ConsumerFetcherManager,name=MaxLag,clientId=([-.\w]+)`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 5):

The JMX PORT you are listening is the broker port. But the Mbean of kafka.consumer: is the consumer jvm metrics. So if you have another JVM that is consume a topic, you can see kafka.consumer Mbeans.

Answer (score 2):

**ConsumerLag** is [an overloaded term in Kafka](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kafka-performance-metrics/), it can stand for:

1. **Consumer's metric**: Calculated difference between a consumer's current log offset and a producer’s current log offset. You can find it under JMX bean, if you're using Java/Scala based consumer (e.g. [pykafka consumer doesn't export metrics](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/issues/776)):

   - kafka `v0.8.2.x`:

     ```
     kafka.consumer:type= ConsumerFetcherManager, name=MaxLag, clientId=([-.\w]+)
     ```
   - kafka `v0.9+`:

     ```
     kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.w]+)
     ```

   Consumer lag used to be stored in ZooKeeper (Kafka `<= v0.8`), newer versions of Kafka have special topic `__consumer_offsets` that stores each consumer's lag. There are tools (e.g. [kafka-manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager)) that can compute lag by consuming messages from this topic and calculating lag. In `kafka-manager` you have to enable this feature for each cluster:

   > [ ] Poll consumer information (Not recommended for large # of consumers)
2. **Broker's metric**: Represent the offset differences between partition leaders and their followers. You can find this metric under JMX bean:

   ```
   kafka.server:type=FetcherLagMetrics,name=ConsumerLag,clientId=([-.\w]+),topic=([-.\w]+),partition=([0-9]+)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This may help to find it for 0.8, but I am currently running a Kafka 0.10 broker and consumer. When using a console consumer, I pointed `jconsole` to this consumer and found on the MBeans TAB: `kafka.consumer`-> `consumer-fetcher-manager-metric` -> `consumer-1` -> `Attributes` -> `records-max-lag`.