# Kafka consumer lag through JMX

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I'm trying to monitor the lag of a consumer group in Kafka 0.10.

Our consumers are keeping track of their offsets in Kafka rather than ZooKeper. This means I can get the figures using the following:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <broker> --describe --group <group-name>
```

This works fine. However, my broker already makes use of the [Prometheus JMX exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) for collecting a number of stats. I've connected JConsole to the brokers but can't see the same data being reported in JMX as reported by `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`.

Is there anyway to get this information from Kafka with JMX *without* needing any additional tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka Consumer - JMX Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799564/kafka-consumer-jmx-properties)

Comment: "Kafka: The Definitive Guide" recommends to use Burrow: https://engineering.linkedin.com/apache-kafka/burrow-kafka-consumer-monitoring-reinvented

Comment: It appears both that book and Burrow share an author. Was there any specific reason why Burrow was suggested? We already have a alerting/monitoring tools in place so I don't need that aspect, just the consumer lag information.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the atrributes `{topic}-{partition}.records-lag` of metric `kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id={client-id}` for all partitions. That should be equivalent to the output of `consumer-groups.sh`

Comment: I don't see any `kafka.consumer` in `jconsole`. I'm connecting to the broker through `jmx` as we making use of a none JMV based consumer.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments & "duplicate" question - this is not broker JMX property, but consumer's

Comment: `kafka.cosumer` is only on consumer clients written in java or scala...its not on the brokers...

Comment: I realize this is old but researching the same issue; if kafka-consumer-metrics is only available now on clients, that does not seem feasible and how would one retrieve max lag for each consumer on a topic?