# Setup JMX Metrics for Kafka Consumer Docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, jmx, metrics

I heard that if I'm using a Java based Kafka Consumer, I can expose JMX metrics from it by adding some parameters ([heard that here and some other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613797/kafka-consumer-lag-through-jmx))

My kafka Consumer is being ran inside a Docker.

Here are the four parameters i'm adding :

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100
-Dom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false  
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
```

I'm adding it in the Entrypoint of my dockerfile. But my jConsole can't connect to it.

Here is my Dockerfile and my docker-compose related service :

```js
FROM openjdk:8u181-jre

ADD ./app /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false", "/app/KafkaConsumer.jar" ]
```

```js
  jk_cons:
    build: ./micro_services/jk_Cons
    ports:
      - "1100:1100"
    volumes:
      - /neito/shared/linux_shared/historian/logging:/app
```

Can someone enlight me on the way of exposing kafka consumer metrics through JMX ?

Have a nice day

Comment: I can post how to do this using Confluent's Kafka docker image, if that helps?

Comment: You need to add `EXPOSE 1100` to the Dockerfile, but what is `jmxremote.port=9090` being added to? Looks like you are using port 1100 in the ENTRYPOINT

Comment: @cricket_007 the 9090 port was the example given in the linked post, in my i'm exposing port 1100 in the docker compose file. And in the entrypoint i'm effectively using `"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100",`. Do you think doing `EXPOSE 1100` in the Dockerfile isn't redundant ? Since I already expose it on the docker compose (I'll give it a try anyway thanks :) )

Comment: @RobinMoffatt i'm always interested, but how changing my Kafka Broker image will help get the Consumer Metrics ? Because I'm already getting JMX metrics of my Kafka Broker easily thanks to the [wurstmeister/kafka Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/). My goal is to get the consumer metrics

Comment: The compose file is a port forward, not saying to exposing it from the image itself. And what do you mean effectively? In the question, you've put a different port than 1100. Note: the problem here isn't really Kafka related since these issues apply to all Java applications in Docker

Comment: It worked by adding `EXPOSE 1100` to the Dockerfile. Thanks for the insight.